# Rearranging inequality

Tags: inequality

Considering this inequality:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)^s < \frac{1}{k!-s!}
$$

Is is possible to rearrange it and obtain any boundaries for k relative to s, other than $k \neq s$?

Comment: So you suppose that $k > s$ here right ? Also do you want to lower bound or upper bound $k$ ?